# Deleting Django migrations file before running 'migrate' command?

Tags: python, django

Say I have this model which has already has a few prior migrations that have been implemented:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from PIL import Image

class Profile(models.Model):
    account = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default = 'default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')
    user_level = models.IntegerField(default = 1)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s Profile' % self.account.username
```

I decide to make a change to the model, changing the user_level field to level_rank and specifying a relationship to a field in a different model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from level_system.models import UserLevel
from PIL import Image

class Profile(models.Model):
    account = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default = 'default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')
    level_rank = models.ForeignKey(UserLevel, on_delete = models.SET_NULL, null = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s Profile' % self.account.username
```

I then run the makemigrations command, but afterwards decide I want to change something else about the Profile model.

What are the consequences of just deleting the migrations file that was created when I ran the makemigrations command?

Essentially, my question is will this confuse the migrations system and corrupt the database, or can you freely delete a migrations file which has **NOT** yet been migrated?

I'm currently using Django v2.0.13

Thanks!

Comment: As far as I know, you can delete it without problems

Comment: As well as checking that the migration has not been run, you should check that there are not any other migrations that [depend on](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/migrations/#dependencies) the migration you wish to delete.

Comment: Yes, you can freely delete a migrations file that has not been applied.  One thing to watch out for is that you don't make too many changes before creating a migration.  If you rename and delete a number of fields at a time, Django might not properly infer field name changes.  Best to be a little more granular when making migrations.  You can always squash migrations later if you'd like to have fewer migrations files.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to those who commented. I decided to take the plunge and delete the migrations file before migrating. I've not encountered any issues yet, although granted the change to my model was minor (only one field changed), so for anyone reading this I'd still recommend caution.